# Xcode new certificate keychain "signing" password

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, signing

I regenerated the apple developer certificate by Xcode.

When I tried to archive new build codesign asked me to input the password of keychain.

Apple account, Mac and iPhone's passwords not worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I left the password field empty and confirmed. This worked for me.